# nuget install not downloading latest version of package

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have uploaded a package that is being used by multiple pipelines. Some pipelines in some projects get the latest version and some pipelines in some projects do not. The key here is they all share the same pipeline template so I'm not quite sure where the problem may be or where to start looking. The call being made is:

```
install ${{ parameters.NugetPckDefinition }} -ExcludeVersion -NoCache -OutputDirectory "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
```

The versions are the following:

- 1.0.3169
- 1.0.3009

Some pipelines are getting 1.0.3169 and some are downloading 1.0.3009. Currently, in order for those pipelines that cannot get the latest version, I call the REST API to get the specific package so that it will show up in Azure Artifacts.

I suspect there are some permissions issues or possibly some caching issues, but the pipelines share the same Build Service account. I checked the permissions on the Agent Pool and they all have the same settings.

Comment: This might sound obvious but; have you double-checked that all pipelines are using the same NugetPckDefinition ?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Yes I double checked. they have the same. I just find it super strange. This is why my suspicion is leaning towards a permission on the project

Comment: Very strange. Time for a call to MS support I reckon.